# Stop Python function running on a Raspberry Pi from a different Pi using TCP/IP connection

Tags: python, tcp, raspberry-pi, robotics

I am programming a robot that has a Raspberry Pi as the microcontroller using Python. The robot has multiple motors and sensors. The robot is controlled using a different Raspberry Pi that sends commands through TCP/IP connection using an ethernet cable (I will refer to this Raspberry Pi as the controller and the robot Raspberry Pi as the Robot). The controller is running a Tkinter UI that has buttons programed to send a message to the robot once they are pressed.

When the robot receives a message from the controller, it processes the message to see what is contained in it, and depending on the content of it, it runs a specific function on the robot program.

The comunications between the robot and controller work fine but the problem I am having now is that once the robot has received a message from the controller, and its running a function, there is no way of stopping the function running on the robot from the controller until it has finished or the power is turned off.

The code running on the robot that receives and processes the mesagges is the following:

```
SERVER = '192.168.0.60'     # This is the server, CPU1 - this one!
PORT = 22001
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
    
# Create socket for the Control Client, Pi4(2) client and Server to use...
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # Using TCP.
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Manage any binding errors...
try:
    s.bind(ADDR)
except socket.error:
    robbie.system_message = "Socket bind failed."

s.listen(5)
    
robbie.system_message = "Awaiting connection request from TT robot controller..."

while True:
    (conn, addr) = s.accept() # Blocking call; this loop runs for each new client connection.
    connected = True
    robbie.system_message = f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected. {threading.activeCount()-1}"
        
     # This IP address is hard coded - very fixed indeed as any deviation will render the robot                         useless.

     if '192.168.0.70' in str(conn):
         robbie.cpu_connected = True
            
        filtered_msg = ''    
        
        msg_route_thread = threading.Thread(target = route_messages, args=(conn, addr))
        msg_route_thread.start()
         
        
def route_messages(conn, addr):
    global robbie, connected
    # This method provides message routing
    
    connected = True
    try:
        while connected:
            # Waiting for messages 
            raw_data = conn.recv(256) # custom command messages can be very long
            data = raw_data.decode()
            raw_data = ""
            x = len(raw_data)
            data = data.strip(' ,')
            
            msg_prefix = data[0:4]
            filtered_msg = data[5:]
            
           
        
            # Each of these procedure calls proceses one message. 
            if msg_prefix == "CTRL":
                robbie.ctrl_latest_message = f"{msg_prefix}~ {filtered_msg}"
                process_ctrl_messages(conn, filtered_msg)
               

def process_ctrl_messages(conn, msg):
    global connected, robbie
    
    robbie.ctrl_latest_message = msg
    
    print(f"CTRL~ ---> {msg}")
    robbie.current_command = msg
    robbie.ctrl_connected = True
    
    # Few exapmles of messages that the robot receives from the controller
        if 'S-HOME' in msg:
            slide_home()
        elif 'P-HOME' in msg:
            pitch_home()
        elif 'R-HOME' in msg:
            roll_home()
```

The code running on the controller that sends messages to the robot is:

```
# ------------------ Communications setup -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
HOST = '192.168.0.60'
PORT = 22001

try:
    time.sleep(10)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    
except socket.error as msg:
    
    print('Check that the robot is powered, is running its own control program, has flashed its lights and is beeping.')
    print(msg)
    exit()
    
print('Controller connected to Tubetech rover.')

# ------------------ Set the various initial states ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
command = ''

# ------------------ Event functions ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ (Some examples of the functions that send the mesagges to the robot.)
def lightsToggle():
    command = 'CTRL~L-TOGGLE'
    s.send(command.encode())
    print(command)
    
def forward():
    # Request the rover to move forwards at the speed currently set.
    command = 'CTRL~FORWARD'
    s.send(command.encode())
    #reply = s.recv(32)
    print(command)
```

As I mentioned before, once the robot has received a message from the controller and it's running a function, the robot does not receive any message until the function has finished. When I get this problem, I have been able to verify that the messages are being sent from the controller but not received in the robot.

I have tried running a different function just for the stop messages on a thread and changing the route messages function but nothing has worked.

Could anyone please give me some guidance on any way of doing it or help me find if I have done something wrong? Even though the robot works fine, I think being able to stop it at anytime using the controller is something essential but I have been stuck on it for a few weeks.

If you feel like I haven't explained something properly or there is something missing please let me know.

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you post traceback?

Comment: You should remove index to empty s.listen() on robot.

Comment: I don't get a traceback on the program, it is just that the messages don't get processed on the robot when a function is being run until it has finished. My thought was that as I have the function to read the messages as a thread, I would be able to send messages from the controller to the robot constantly and process them. Also,  I have tried removing the index on the s.listen() but I still have the same problem.